# JWT token not expire after logout in laravel 5.4 and 5.5

Tags: php, jwt, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5

I am using JWT Package in laravel and use in logout api `JWT::invalidate()` function but token is not expire.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the specifics of the package you are using, but in general, JWT tokens cannot be revoked, thats part of the spec and how they work. Because the token is self contained, and doesnt rely on any outside session storage

Answer (score 0):

You can't make the token expire like that because the JWT token includes the expiry time. Instead the `JWT::invalidate()` method adds that token to a blacklist, so while the expiry time remains the same the token should not be accepted.

You can set a short grace period to allow for things like parallel AJAX requests when the token is refreshed on each request. Maybe you're experiencing this issue because the token is still in the grace period after being invalidated?